# How to make a bot ping a user using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm kinda new to bot developing, but I've made a command called &pat and I want it to work like this:
You do &pat @user and I want it to respond like this: @user-executing-the-command, you have successfully patted @user-mentioned-in-the-command. I've come up with this code so far and it works all well apart from pinging the patted person. I *does* ping them, but it shows @invalid-user, and idk how to fix that. My code:

```
var pattedone = message.mentions.members.first();

    if(!pattedone) return message.reply('please mention the one who should be patted');
    
    message.reply(`you have successfully patted ${pattedone}`);
```

Do you know how to fix that @invalid-user thing? Thanks. [Here is screenshot of the bot's response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lg7G.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Discord.js Documentation](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#how-discord-mentions-work)

> Discord uses a special syntax to embed mentions in a message. For user mentions it is the user's ID with <@ at the start and > at the end, like this: <@86890631690977280>

With this in mind. Simply change

```
message.reply(`you have successfully patted ${pattedone}`);
```

to this

```
message.reply(`you have successfully patted <@${pattedone.id}>`);
```

**EDIT**

You'll also need to update

```
var pattedone = message.mentions.members.first();
```

to

```
var pattedone = message.mentions.users.first();
```

Comment: It kinda worked, but only if the patted person is the one who executed the command. If I execute it and mention myself, it shows it right, but if I mention anyone else it still shows invalid-user. I even copied your line of code to make sure I haven't messed up, but it works like that. :/ Everything else stayed the same. Any idea why it is half-broken? Update: It is half broken only on mobile, PC (at least web browser version) shows it right. That might be some difference between mobile and PC version? But idk, any help or answer would be welcome :)

Comment: I just looked at one of my code examples. There may be another line you'll need to change as well. Let me update my answer @mkpanda

Comment: I changed the members to users in the line, but it still works only on PC. I don't think that having an emoji after the tag would break it on mobile, but I don't know. @Chris

Comment: Is there a space between the mention and the emoji? If there isn't, that might break things.

Comment: The line looks like this, there is a space: *message.reply(`you have successfully patted <@${pattedone.id}> <:viprinpat:746051047876984903>`);*

Comment: Is there any additional code that is missing in your example that would help? My example should work and is what I'm using in one of my current bots that is live

Comment: Nope, that's all

Comment: Does the ping work on mobile for you? Because that's where it doesn't work for me, on PC it's working fine. @Chris

Comment: @mkpanda Yeah, it works for me on mobile and desktop

Comment: That's really weird... So my code is right, but something weird happens. I also tried removing the emoji from the response but nothing changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220233/discussion-between-chris-and-mk-panda).

Answer (score 0):

you can mention a user with the following "method":

```
let mention = `<@${userId}>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord mentions work like this: `<@user-id>`. Simply replace `user-id` with the ID of the "victim". You can also mention roles using `<&channel-id>` or text channels using `<#channel-id>`.